# Learnstreet Ruby Lesson 11.5 Transfer state between objects

Tags: ruby

I've been stuck on this Learnstreet lesson for a day now.  The exercise prompts:

> Can you now implement a method called transfer! which takes two parameters, amount and other_account. The method should withdraw the specified amount from the current object and deposit it into other_account object.

The code in the editor goes as follows:

```
class BankAccount

    attr_accessor :name, :balance, :address

    def initialize(name, balance, address)
        @name =  name
        @balance = balance
        @address = address
    end

    def withdraw!(amount)
        if @balance - amount > 0
            @balance = @balance - amount
        end
        @balance
    end

    def deposit!(amount)
        @balance += amount
    end

    # your code here

end

alices_account = BankAccount.new("Alice Cooper", 2500, "456 University Avenue")
bobs_account = BankAccount.new("Bob Ventura", 2100, "3500 Fox Street")
```

I know that you need to set up a method with def transfer!(amount, other_account).  However I do not know what to put in the bottom after alices_account and bobs_account.

Answer (score 0):

You'd call `transfer!` on one of the objects, passing in the other, e.g.,

```
bobs_account.transfer!(500, alices_account)
```

You're just calling a method on an instance, like `"foo".size` or `[1, 2, 3].each` etc. The only difference is that *you've* created the method you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that you need to set up a method with def transfer!(amount, other_account).

So basically you have to create `BankAccount#transfer!` that withdraw some money from the object that calls it and deposit the sum into the "other" `BankAccount` object.

The solution is pretty trivial since you have the `BankAccount#withdraw!` and `BankAccount#deposit!` already set up:

```
def transfer!(amount, other_account)
    withdraw! amount
    other_account.deposit! amount
end
```

> However I do not know what to put in the bottom after alices_account and bobs_account.

The exercise doesn't require you to do anything with the latter. If you were supposed to do something you would need to know the amount of "money" to transfer from `alices_account` to `bobs_account` an viceversa and then go with:

```
# assuming x to be the amount to transfer
alices_account.transfer! x, bobs_account
```

or:

```
# assuming x to be the amount to transfer
bobs_account.transfer! x, alices_account
```

---

Ok now. I've spent an hour to complete all the 10 course before that one and this is what I discovered. At some point you [get to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQb0V.png) the last two lines of your code.

Then a weird thing happens. The code generated by the exercise contains a `. To` near the end [which is obviously a syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqucu.png). By removing that line and adding the method I provided above [you get to pass the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7BiR.png).

Comment: I downvoted for providing the OP with an answer that he is clearly trying to come up with himself.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the . To was extraneous.  That helps a lot.